# Alinear dos Typography al hacer la pantalla pequeña

Tags: css, reactjs, material-ui, design

Estoy intentando de alinear dos Typography cuando la pantalla se hace pequeña, estoy haciéndolo con grid, pero no logro hacer que los elementos suban.
He intentado bajar las columnas de 12 a 6 pero entonces se desconfigura todo. Alguien me podría decir que estoy haciendo mal y  como solucionarlo.

**Estos son los títulos de la izquierda**

```
  return (

        <Grid container justifyContent="space-between">

            <Grid item xs={12} sm="auto" >

                <Typography variant="h6" component="h2" gutterBottom>
                    Clima
                </Typography>

            </Grid>

            <Grid item xs={12} sm="auto">

                <Typography variant="h6" component="h2" >
                    Temperatura 
                </Typography>

            </Grid>

            <Grid item xs={12} sm="auto">

                <Typography variant="h6" component="h2" gutterBottom>
                    Maxima 
                </Typography>

            </Grid>

            <Grid item xs={12} sm="auto">

                <Typography variant="h6" component="h2" gutterBottom>
                    Minima 
                </Typography>

            </Grid>

        </Grid>
    )
```

**Y aquí es donde irán las respuestas**

```
return (
    <Grid container justifyContent="space-between">

        <Grid item xs={12} sm="auto">

            <Typography variant="h6" component="h2" align="right" gutterBottom>
                Clima
            </Typography>

        </Grid>

        <Grid item xs={12} sm="auto">

            <Typography variant="h6" component="h2" align="right" gutterBottom>
                Temperatura
            </Typography>

        </Grid>

        <Grid item xs={12} sm="auto">

            <Typography variant="h6" component="h2" align="right" gutterBottom>
                Maxima 
            </Typography>

        </Grid>

        <Grid item xs={12} sm="auto">

            <Typography variant="h6" component="h2" align="right" gutterBottom>
                Minima 
            </Typography>

        </Grid>

    </Grid>
)
```

**Ambos componentes los renderizo aquí**

```
return (
    <form autoComplete="off">
        <div>

            <Typography className={ classes.title } color="textPrimary" align="center" gutterBottom >
                Weather App
            </Typography>

            <Typography variant="h5" component="h2" >
                Nombre del país:  
            </Typography>

            <TextField 
                id="standard-basic standard-error" 
                className={ classes.entrada } 
                label="Nombre" 
                margin="normal" 
                fullWidth={true} 
                error={empty}
                helperText="El campo es obligatorio"
            />     

           
            <Titulos />
            <Datos />
            

        </div>
    </form>
)
```

Aquí el como se ve actualmente.

[image: Como podria solucionarlo?]

Si alguien me pudiera ayudar se lo agradecería bastante!!

Saludos!!

Answer (score 0):

Para no meterme en Grid y hacerlo rápido, envuelve en un contenedor tus 2 vistas y los alineas con inline-flex.

```
<div style={{ display: inline-flex}}>
  <Titulos /> 
  <Datos />
</div>

Hay muchas formas de hacer esto, pero te tocará aprender más de CSS (CSS GRID o FLEX).
```